# Can you filter a listagg to only return multiple results?

Tags: sql, oracle, listagg

I have an SQL query I'm running on SQL Developer that uses a listagg to return one or more items for a single field.

As it is, the query returns records in which the listagg has one or more items.

What I would like to do is filter out the records in which the listagg has only one item in favor of only returning records in which the listagg has MORE THAN one item.

This is the part of the query that uses the listagg - along with some psuedo-code of what I want to do:

```
Select "SingleItem", listagg(distinct "MultipleItems", ', ') as "MultipleItems"
FROM my_results mr
WHERE EXISTS
(SELECT "SingleItem", "MultipleItems"
   FROM my_results
)
AND <"MultipleItems" contains more than 1 item>
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could just use `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT`

```sql
SELECT
  "SingleItem",
  listagg(distinct "MultipleItems", ', ') as "MultipleItems"
FROM my_results mr
GROUP BY
  "SingleItem"
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT "MultipleItems") > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

One option might be this: use your current query as a CTE (i.e. a *source*) for the final query which counts number of commas in "MultipleItems":

- if there's only one item there, no commas at all (so count is 0)
- otherwise,

  - if there are two items, there'll be 1 comma
  - three items - 2 commas
  - etc.

So:

```
WITH
   temp
   AS
      (SELECT "SingleItem", LISTAGG (DISTINCT "MultipleItems", ', ') AS "MultipleItems"
         FROM my_results mr
        WHERE EXISTS (SELECT "SingleItem", "MultipleItems" FROM my_results))
SELECT *
  FROM temp
 WHERE REGEXP_COUNT ("MutlitpeItems", ',') > 0
```

---

BTW, in Oracle, we really, really rarely enclose object names (columns included) into double quotes. Nothing good in that, only trouble.

Comment: Thanks everyone.  All of these were very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell what to do as it depends on your columns "SingleItem", "MultipleItems" for which we don't know the content. Main issue is if MultipleItems column is already a list of some kind and if that is the case then the delimiter used is most important. Because of that - below are two MULTI columns, one for comma delimited list and another for plain text.

```sql
WITH    -- S a m p l e    D a t a :
    my_results AS
        ( Select 1 "ID", 'A' "SINGLE", 'A' "MULTI", 'X' "MULTI_2" From Dual Union All 
          Select 2, 'A', 'A, A', 'X'        From Dual Union All 
          Select 3, 'B', 'B', 'X'           From Dual Union All 
          Select 4, 'C', 'A, B, C', 'X'     From Dual Union All 
          Select 5, 'B', 'B, B', 'Y'        From Dual Union All 
          Select 6, 'B', 'AA, BB, CC', 'Y'  From Dual 
        ),
```

Option 1. - making LISTAGG out of comma delimited list column - once with another comma and other with slash as delimiter. (using opt_1 CTE)

```sql
    opt_1 AS    --  1  making list out of list (MULTI)
        ( Select    SINGLE, 
                    LISTAGG(Distinct MULTI, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (Order By MULTI) "LIST_OF_MULTI_COMMA",
                    LISTAGG(Distinct MULTI, ' / ') WITHIN GROUP (Order By MULTI) "LIST_OF_MULTI_SLASH"
          From      my_results mr
          Group By  SINGLE
        ),
```

```sql
/*    R e s u l t  ( opt_1 ) :
SINGLE  LIST_OF_MULTI_COMMA   LIST_OF_MULTI_SLASH
------  --------------------  ----------------------------
A         A, A, A                 A / A, A
B         AA, BB, CC, B, B, B     AA, BB, CC / B / B, B
C         A, B, C                 A, B, C                  */
```

... this shows that if we make a list out of list using same delimiter we will have different number of elements than with  changed delimiter.  Counting elements by delimiter is below:

```sql
--  M a i n    S Q L   1
Select    SINGLE, LIST_OF_MULTI_COMMA, LIST_OF_MULTI_SLASH,
          Length(LIST_OF_MULTI_COMMA) - Length(Replace(LIST_OF_MULTI_COMMA, ',', '')) + 1 "COMMA_ELEMENTS",
          Length(LIST_OF_MULTI_SLASH) - Length(Replace(LIST_OF_MULTI_SLASH, '/', '')) + 1 "SLASH_ELEMENTS"
From      opt_1
```

```sql
/*    R e s u l t    1 :
SINGLE  LIST_OF_MULTI_COMMA  LIST_OF_MULTI_SLASH  COMMA_ELEMENTS  SLASH_ELEMENTS
------  -------------------  -------------------  --------------  --------------
A         A, A, A                 A / A, A                     3              2
B         AA, BB, CC, B, B, B     AA, BB, CC / B / B, B        6              3
C         A, B, C                 A, B, C                      3              1  */
```

... above resultset could be filtered by COMMA_ELEMENTS or by SLASH_ELEMENTS

```sql
...
WHERE SLASH_ELEMENTS > 1
```

Option 2.  -  making a list of SINGLE - using opt_2 CTE

```sql
    opt_2 AS    --  2  making list out of SINGLE
        ( Select    MULTI_2, LISTAGG(Distinct SINGLE, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (Order By SINGLE) "LIST_OF_SINGLE"
          From      my_results mr
          Group By  MULTI_2
        )
```

```sql
/*  R e s u l t  ( opt_2 ) :
MULTI_2   LIST_OF_SINGLE
-------   ---------------------------
X           A, B, C
Y           B                            */
```

```sql
--  M a i n    S Q L   2
Select    MULTI_2, LIST_OF_SINGLE,
          Length(LIST_OF_SINGLE) - Length(Replace(LIST_OF_SINGLE, ',', '')) + 1 "ELEMENTS"
From      opt_2
```

```sql
/*    R e s u l t    2 :
MULTI_2  LIST_OF_SINGLE  ELEMENTS
-------  --------------  --------
X          A, B, C              3
Y          B                    1       */
```

... this also could be filtered by number of element in a way you want

```sql
...
WHERE ELEMENTS > 1
```

```
**NOTE**:    
If you need to count elements in list using delimiter then you should make sure to use the delimiter which doesn't exist in the data you are making the list of!
```